# SMTP networking failed on AWS

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, exchange

I have a home broadband network on which I also run an email server. As my provider won't give me a fixed IP address due to my age 16 and I am preparing for certification for part time job. So on my gaming machine I created exchange 2016 server. I felt the simple solution I create a VPN between a virtual server and my home server.

I've done that fine, I installed OpenVPN and that connection is fine. My home network runs on 192.168.1.x, the VPN runs on 172.27.224.x with the client (my mail server) having the address 172.27.224.2 on its end of the tunnel. The vps has a real world ip address on the Internet side.

I did ip forwarding so I can happily send traffic out from the client, email, web browse, etc, but I'm at a loss with how to forward traffic from the Internet on the SMTP port inbound to my mail server.

Here are my networking rules which I added for prerouting and post routing.

```
openvpnas@ip-172-31-34-110:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -d 13.58.xxx.xx -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.224.2
openvpnas@ip-172-31-34-110:~$ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 25 -d 172.27.224.2 -j SNAT --to-source 172.27.224.1
openvpnas@ip-172-31-34-110:~$ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport 25 -d 172.27.224.2 -j ACCEPT
```

In debugging i found I can use wireshark for windows to capture packets i am new in that but found a basic filter for tcp.srcport==25 and dumped the traffic but it's huge. I didn;t found IP address of VPS Server which should be 172.27.224.1 i guess. then after googling a bit more I found I can use tcpdump on Linux vps and here's the result for that.

```
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
12:37:51.498699 IP (tos 0x2,ECT(0), ttl 106, id 28057, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    www.adminkit.net.55303 > ip-172-31-34-110.us-east-2.compute.internal.smtp: Flags [SEW], cksum 0xe8da (correct), seq 1003591980, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
12:37:51.498749 IP (tos 0x2,ECT(0), ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    ip-172-31-34-110.us-east-2.compute.internal.smtp > www.adminkit.net.55303: Flags [R.], cksum 0x4a5a (correct), seq 0, ack 1003591981, win 0, length 0
12:37:52.122587 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 106, id 28058, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    www.adminkit.net.55303 > ip-172-31-34-110.us-east-2.compute.internal.smtp: Flags [S], cksum 0xe99a (correct), seq 1003591980, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
12:37:52.122621 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    ip-172-31-34-110.us-east-2.compute.internal.smtp > www.adminkit.net.55303: Flags [R.], cksum 0x4a5a (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 012:37:52.747621 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 106, id 28059, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
    www.adminkit.net.55303 > ip-172-31-34-110.us-east-2.compute.internal.smtp: Flags [S], cksum 0xfda9 (correct), seq 1003591980, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
12:37:52.747659 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 64, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 40)
    ip-172-31-34-110.us-east-2.compute.internal.smtp > www.adminkit.net.55303: Flags [R.], cksum 0x4a5a (correct), seq 0, ack 1, win 0, length 0
```

I can see traffic coming from outside network but it's not routing to my local exchange server client.

but if I do telnet from my VPS i can connect with end node

```
openvpnas@ip-172-31-34-110:~$ telnet 172.27.224.2 25
Trying 172.27.224.2...
Connected to 172.27.224.2.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 locmx01 Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 21 Dec 2020 04:39:18 -0800
^]
```

I hope I've given you enough information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting your mail server to the Internet (or to another ex-organizational mailing system that uses SMTP) you must always make sure that the rest of the world can successfully resolve your domain’s MX Record, failing to do so will cause e-mail traffic not to be delivered to you.(**[Configure MX Records for Incoming SMTP E-Mail Traffic](https://petri.com/configure_mx_records_for_incoming_smtp_email_traffic)**)

For external mail flow which was from VPS to your Exchange Server, you need configure a MX record and add the IP address or FQDN of your email server to the record.

Comment: The problem is MX records are for the domain but for testing we should be able to contact SMTP server based on IP address but  I can't reach out to my aws public address, connection will be dropped on aws machine it will not pass it to the client Check the tcp dump of AWS in question..